# Send keystroke combination to USB device [simulated keyboard]

Tags: python, keyboard, usb, libusb

I'm trying to fix a FireTV stick stuck in boot loop, without a OTG-Y cable to access safe mode. To do so, you have to press *CTRL + ALT + MENU + i + PRINT* in a high frequency on a keyboard connected to the device.

The FireTV stick is connected to the usb port of my computer over a micro-usb cable.

Not sure if this is works at all. I'm stuck at sending the keystrokes to the device. I don't know if it's the right MODE for the usb interface. It looks like bulk_write is sending keycodes from the write() function in an array:

> 2023-09-05 14:40:29,556 DEBUG:usb.backend.libusb1:_LibUSB.bulk_write(<usb.backend.libusb1._DeviceHandle object at 0x000001FCACCFF0A0>, 1, 0, array('B', [107, 101, 121, 99, 111, 100, 101, 115, 32, 105, 110, 32, 98, 117, 108, 107]), 1000)

I expect that the FireTV OS enters safe mode.

My python code:  (using libusb, on Windows):

```
#import libusb
#libusb.config(LIBUSB="libusb C shared library absolute path")
#libusb.config(LIBUSB=None)


import os
os.environ['PYUSB_DEBUG'] = 'debug'
import usb.core
import usb.util
import libusb_package

# FireTV
# dev ID 1949:03a1 on Bus 001 Address 009
# iSerialNumber          :    0x3 G4N0VM1014050SWD

firetv_usb = libusb_package.find(idVendor=0x1949, idProduct=0x03a1)

if firetv_usb is None:
    raise ValueError('Device not found')

firetv_usb.set_configuration()
cfg = firetv_usb.get_active_configuration()
intf = cfg[(0,0)]

endpoint = usb.util.find_descriptor(
    intf,
    custom_match = \
    lambda e: \
        usb.util.endpoint_direction(e.bEndpointAddress) == \
        usb.util.ENDPOINT_OUT
)

assert endpoint is not None

# safe mode key combi: CTRL + ALT + MENU + i + PRINT
# keycodes: ? + ? + ? + 105 + ?
endpoint.write('keycode combination')
```